# Javascript "this" through different scope

Tags: javascript, events, this, anonymous-function, parent-node

Please, read and try the code below. Click on "foo" paragraph. Looking at the browser console, I don't see the expected results, while if I click on "bar", I do.

Why is that happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root">
      <div>
        <p id="foo">foo</p>
      </div>
      <p id="bar">bar</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var p_list = document.getElementsByTagName('P');
      for (var n=0; n<p_list.length; n++) {
        p_list[n].onclick = function() {
          console.log('ONCLICK - id: ' + this.id + ' - ' + getC( this ) + '\n');
        };
      }
      function getC( P ) {
        if (P.parentNode.className === 'root') {
          console.log('INSIDE FUNCTION - id: ' + P.id + ' - ' + P.parentNode);
          return P.parentNode;
        } else {
          getC( P.parentNode );
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Live code: http://jsbin.com/izuleg/1/edit

Comment: Please ask a question, don't just say you don't expect the result.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq] if you haven't already. For these sorts of questions it's generally helpful to create a [reduced test case on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and to describe what your expected results are.

Comment: Notice that this will cause an exception if applied on an element that is not a descendant of any element with exact class "root"

Comment: I'm sorry, I retry. Using "this" I can not correctly interface the referent of event ('p') inside the anonymous function and in getC. My question is: maybe I improperly use the this keyword? Thanks

Comment: Rather than add details through comments, you should edit the post for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing a `return` statement in your `else` clause. It should be:

```
...

} else {
    return getC( P.parentNode );
}
```

Note that you're using a recursive function (a function that calls itself), so you should probably add extra precautions to make it return something in exceptional cases (such as, there is no node with class "root"), otherwise you'll get an infinite recursion, and a stack overflow error.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the recursive function intentionally, but I was convinced that I didn't need to return itself.

Thanks. Now I can work about the exceptions.

Comment: The inner call did return a value, but your code was ignoring it. Adding that return statement made the outer call return the value of the inner call. Each value only returns to the context where it was called from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake. You should return the result of getC instead of just calling it.

```
function getC( P ) {
    if (P.parentNode.className === 'root') {
      console.log('INSIDE FUNCTION - id: ' + P.id + ' - ' + P.parentNode);
      return P.parentNode;
    } else {
      return getC( P.parentNode );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `<div>` and `</div>` tags, please check:

```
    <div class="root">
          <div>
            <p id="foo">foo</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p id="bar">bar</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```